# PHP - variable scope in recursively function

Tags: php

First assumption: Assume, we defined a variable (its name is $tmp) in a function(functioin name is 'ExpMenu') for temporary calculating and in end of function we return this variable.

Second assumption: Assume, we call that function recursively for create a navigation menu base on a multidimensional array.

My question is about scope of that variable ($tmp). In every call funtion, will its value overwritten? In other words, by every function call we lose previous value?

For more detail, please review below code:

```
/// --- { Declaration Block
$content = array(
    array(
        'level'=>'1',
        'order'=>'1',
        'text'=>'New Solution WorkFlow',
        'is_parent'=>'yes',
        'child'=> array(
            array(
                'level'=>'2',
                'order'=>'1',
                'text'=>'Define New Solution',
                'is_parent'=>'no',
                'url'=>'#'
            ),
            array(
                'level'=>'2',
                'order'=>'2',
                'text'=>'View Solutions',
                'is_parent'=>'no',
                'url'=>'#'
            ),
            array(
                'level'=>'2',
                'order'=>'3',
                'text'=>'View Solutions',
                'is_parent'=>'no',
                'url'=>'#'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'level'=>'1',
        'order'=>'2',
        'text'=>'Solution Modify WorkFlow',
        'is_parent'=>'yes',
        'child'=> array(
            array(
                'level'=>'2',
                'order'=>'1',
                'text'=>'Request For Solution Modify',
                'is_parent'=>'no',
                'url'=>'#'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'level'=>'1',
        'order'=>'3',
        'text'=>'Solution Close WorkFlow',
        'is_parent'=>'yes',
        'child'=> array(
            array(
                'level'=>'2',
                'order'=>'1',
                'text'=>'Declare For Solution Close',
                'is_parent'=>'no',
                'url'=>'#'
            )
        )
    )
);

function ExpMenu($item_array ) {

    $tmp='';
    foreach ($item_array as $item) {
        if ($item['is_parent']=='yes') {
            $tmp = '<li class="hasChild">' . $item["text"] . '<ul>';
            $tmp .= ExpMenu($item['child']);
            $tmp .= '</ul></li>';
        } else {
            $tmp = '<li>';
            $tmp .= '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">'. $item['text'] . '</a>' ;
            $tmp .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $tmp;

}
/// --- }

$menu='<div><ul>';
$menu .= ExpMenu($content);
$menu.='</ul></div>';


echo $m . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams by every call function we lose pervious value.

I thank [@l0rkaY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329532/csklrnd) for her/him solution, But I found another solution that doesn't need add new parameter in my function.

Because $tmp scope is in 'ExpMenu' function and we call recursively function, therefore variable still alive and wasn't terminated.

So, I modify my function a bit:

```
function ExpMenu($item_array ) {

    $tmp='';
    foreach ($item_array as $item) {
        if ($item['is_parent']=='yes') {
            $tmp .= '<li class="hasChild">' . $item["text"] . '<ul>';
            $tmp .= ExpMenu($item['child']);
            $tmp .= '</ul></li>';
        } else {
            $tmp .= '<li>';
            $tmp .= '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">'. $item['text'] . '</a>' ;
            $tmp .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $tmp;

}
```

Comment: *"It seams by every call function we lose previous value."* -- each call of the function has its own set of local variables; nothing is lost, nothing is overwritten. Ignore the recurrence, think of the inner call as a different operation that returns a string. Each call of the function creates a local variable `$tmp` (different than `$tmp` of other calls), appends some strings to it then returns it. The problem in your original call is **not related to the recurrence**. The first assignments in the `if` and `else` blocks reset the value of `$tmp` on each iteration.

Comment: [@axiac](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) exactly right with you. Problem related to first assignments, that by modify code like above, it will solving.

Comment: [@axiac](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) please submit your answer
>("Each call of the function creates a local variable $tmp (different than $tmp of other calls), appends some strings to it then returns it")
until i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

I assume your actual problem is, that your function generates only single item with a single child item.

It's because you are overwriting your previous item in your if/else blocks. That's why you only get the last item.
You just need to concatenate them to the existing items.

```
function ExpMenu($item_array ) {

    $tmp='';
    foreach ($item_array as $item) {
        if ($item['is_parent']=='yes') {
            $tmp .= '<li class="hasChild">' . $item["text"] . '<ul>';
            $tmp .= ExpMenu($item['child']);
            $tmp .= '</ul></li>';
        } else {
            $tmp .= '<li>';
            $tmp .= '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">'. $item['text'] . '</a>' ;
            $tmp .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $tmp;

}
```

Comment: Thank you [@gre_gor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/794749/gre-gor). You exactly detected my actual problem. But my question is about scope of variable in recursive functions.
It is the most interesting that you and me found same answer.